# Spinner in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, spinner, textfield

I created a number TextField and a spinner with JavaFX. I want that my spinner contains numbers from 1 to that number already entered in the textfield. Is that possible and how?? I need your help please .Thanks

Comment: Where are you actually stuck? Assuming you use an `IntegerSpinnerValueFactory`, you would just call `setMax(...)` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be help to you, frist call listener on your text field and change the max value of spinner by :
UPDATE: Make your spinner like that :

```
IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory = new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 10);
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<Integer>(valueFactory);
```

and then use this method in listener that you call on your text Field

```
valueFactory.setMax(Integer.parseInt(Your_Text_Field.getText());
```

Comment: it gives me a NullPointerException , error occured with during conversion i think

Comment: I update the answer you can make your spinner as  given in  my answer

Comment: There is no error but my spinner does not contain any value!

Comment: I figure it out!! it is working now!! you are a life saver thank you a lot!!